# Trying to call methods between classes created dynamically

Tags: c#

I have been trying to work out how to call a method in a different class. Both classes are created dynamically at run-time. Most of the issues I have seen here relate to inheritance, which is different from what I have (I think.)

I am still fairly new to C#, and am trying to test some concepts out.

The first class is something like this:

```
public class Record
{
    CustomPanel _panel;

    public void recordFunc(){}
}
```

The internally created class has something like this:

```
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    List<Control> _myControls = new List<Control>;
    // _myControls[0] += new EventHandler(myFunc);

    public void myFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // parentClass.recordFunc();
    }
}
```

My objective is to create a Record at run-time from a database call. At that point, it creates a Panel (from my CustomPanel class) that gets added to a FlowLayoutControl. When events are fired from the panel's internal controls, I need to have it update parts of the parent Record class.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Clarification: "Both classes are created at runtime." Do you mean that you are dynamically compiling new *classes* using an IL emitter, or simply that you are creating a new *instance* of objects of this type?

Comment: Guess I didn't word that right. I am creating new instances at run-time, as opposed to creating new classes at run-time. That'd be more work than is necessary for this little project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but it seems you want to know how to call a function on a class, when you don't know the class type at runtime, but it could be one or many record types. Is that correct?

If so, a way to cleanly achieve the above is to implement an interface on your derived types and call the interface method. For instance, if you have multiple "Record" classes and don't know the type at runtime, try the following:

```
public interface IRecord 
{
    void RecordFunc();
} 

public class ARecord : IRecord
{
    public void RecordFunc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ARecord.RecordFunc");
    }
}

public class AnotherRecord : IRecord
{
    public void RecordFunc()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AnotherRecord.RecordFunc");
    }
}

public class CustomPanel : Panel
{    
    private IRecord _parentRecord;

    // Where parentRecord could be ARecord or AnotherRecord
    public class CustomPanel(IRecord parentRecord)
    {
        _parentRecord = parentRecord;
    }

    public void MyFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _parentRecord.RecordFunc();
    }
}
```

If that's not what you're looking for, please clarify.

Comment: That is also a good idea. In clarification, it isn't so much that there are multiple record types being loaded, but rather that i need to bind event handlers to controls being dynamically placed into the panel when I add it to a Flow Layout Control during program execution. Each control needs to be able to update the parent Record object. I think I may put it the other way and have the record be the child of the CustomPanel object, since I would then have easier access to the scope of the Record object. I just feel that in doing so I am violating some type of good coding practice.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure but if each control is representing a record, then definitely associate the control to a record 1:1, and "present" the data for this record. There's nothing wrong with having a collection of Children in your parent control and communicating between the two. Just be careful if you start sub'ing events to unsub else you can create a memory leak in .NET

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic instance of the `Record` class available from within a `CustomPanel` just because a `Record` instance contains a `CustomPanel`. You'll have to set up such a relationship yourself. E.g.

```
public class Record
{
    CustomPanel _panel;
    public CustomPanel panel
    {
         get { return _panel; }
         set { _panel = value; _panel.parent = this; }
    }

    public void recordFunc(){}
}

public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    public Record parent { get; set; }

    public void myFunc(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        parent.recordFunc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I was hoping there'd be a magic instance available, since C# is filled with nifty little tools like that.